# String to Decimal conversion with Culture

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cultureinfo

I have a piece of code that read data from excel file store it in DB.

```
`decimal num = Convert.ToDecimal(rowOptions["excel_cl_name"]);`
```

But it does not work properly for **NL** culture. Let say when value is 878,90 it should be 878.9000 but it becomes 87890.0000. When value is 123,5 , it should be 123.5000 but it becomes 1235.0000. When value is 123 then it is 123.0000.

I cannot replace the ',' with space and divide the number by 100 as for other 2 cases it will fail.

Note: In database precision is 4.

Is there any way I can force the culture to be en-us always ?
Is there a better way to manage it?
I can also have value like 12.345,90 which is 12,345.9000.

Comment: Have you tried like this?
`string amountFromDB = "878,90";`
            `decimal actualAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(amountFromDB, new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid, yes tried, It throw  Input string was not in a correct format  exception

Comment: Have you traced what was the value when exception occurred?

Comment: Is the data in the Excel file stored as a Decimal or as a String?

Comment: Does Nz culture has Comma as decimal separator or dot ? I believe it is dot and hence the result.